# Deploy a pre-built RoR application to a local (Linux) machine from source

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've inherited a RoR application which I'm in the process of working towards deploying on Heroku.

Firstly I need to deploy on the dev environment but I can't seem to make this happen. I've installed Ruby rvm, Gems and Rails but outwith creating a new application Rails keeps throwing a myriad of errors.

I'm running Ubuntu 11 and the file structure of the application is that of a freshly created app.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks,
SOliver.

Comment: Please update your answer with the errors that are being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow these suggestions I found on Redmine website:

> **RubyGems 1.3.7 or higher is required with following limitations :**
>
> - Rails 2.3.5 will fail with RubyGems 1.5.0 or later, stick to previous versions of RubyGems
> - Rails 2.3.11 will fail with RubyGems 1.7.0 or later, stick to
>     previous versions of RubyGems

source: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

Ubuntu 11.xx might have the "wrong" (incompatible) packages in the repo, so you can try to install the "right" versions manually.

***Note**: remove ruby, rubygems etc first. Then try this:*

```
apt-get install zip unzip ruby
cd /tmp
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/70697/rubygems-1.3.7.zip
unzip rubygems-1.3.7.zip
cd rubygems-1.3.7
ruby setup.rb all
cd ..
rm -r rubygems-1.3.7 rubygems-1.3.7.zip
ln /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/bin/gem

gem install rails -v=2.3.11
gem install rack -v=1.1.1
gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n
```